# What's the thought behind the 5-rep limit for asking questions on meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta, privileges

Here is a user who has wronged the system in some manner, and honestly seems to be trying to make amends.  They wanted to come to meta and address this here, in my opinion properly, to avoid cluttering the main SO site.

> [image: the Stack Overflow post]

The actual question (which is likely going to be deleted shortly): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25797378/i-need-help-please-tell-me-what-to-do-and-i-wont-ask-such-questions-again?noredirect=1#comment40350627_25797378

How can we prevent this?  The user, at 1 rep on SO, wanted to come to meta and work it out.  I don't have an answer for this, except lowering the posting requirements to 1 rep in meta.  They have since been upvoted to 11 rep (at the time I took the screenshot) and the rep will likely be up and down for awhile as the question is slapped around.

---

I did actually create a new account on meta for the purposes of testing this.  It's a very clear answer:

> [image: The You Need 5 Rep message]

Comment: Background reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238538/meta-participation-privilege-should-require-5-rep-or-something-else http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153414/reputation-requirements-for-posting-on-meta-stack-exchange-and-per-site-metas

Comment: I think the main purpose is to prevent every first-time user who gets a dusting-off on SO from loudly complaining here. There have been a number of questions like that on MSO already; most were, if I summarize correctly, answered with "well it wasn't a *stellar* question, now was it?"

Comment: Is it possible for under 5 rep users to have their questions migrated from SO to MSO?

Comment: Stack Overflow Academy

Comment: I have to concur with @Jongware.  Most 1 rep users need to consult the Help Center first, not ask a question on Meta.

Comment: @Unihedron: Stack Overflow Academy is dead.  Long live Meta.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - so maybe put a link to the help center on the same page that alerts you for the inability to post until you reach 5 point s.

Comment: The biggest thing it cuts down on is lost or question-banned users asking programming questions here. The old Meta.SO used to get a lot of those, probably because of the high Google rank and the whole .stackoverflow.com in the URL. The 5-rep barrier has all but eliminated those, thankfully. They can still ask on Meta.SE if they want, which doesn't have that reputation limit.

Comment: @eddie_cat: I doubt it - even if we could, they wouldn't be able to use the site until they had enough rep.

Comment: @BradLarson: the advice for the user in that case would probably have been to ask at Meta.SE, right?  At least that would have allowed for an open dialog.

Comment: @insta - Meta.SE is one alternative, since they do want that to be open to even new users. They can then migrate SO-specific questions that warrant it back here. Their question isn't that specific to SO, so it might actually fit on Meta.SE.

Answer (score 5):

If Stack sites were new, then perhaps removing that threshold would be beneficial to everyone.
However, touching on what @RobertHarvey said, I think it's fine, with both help centre *and* a plethora of most common new user questions already on Meta.

New users tend not to ask about "deep" Stack things which only more seasoned users will ask, and by then have > 5 rep.

So I think we have it mostly covered for them by now.

It could be a bit unfair if a user with <5 rep has a question not covered by help centre/previous questions.
However if they're decent, they'll gain that *tiny* rep quickly, then come back and ask their civil, valid, and non-dupe question at a later date.

If they are not decent, and are just after a vent, although every user should be able to have their say I *quietly* don't really mind in this case. It'll likely just be a dupe, non-constructive, uncivil, and just moaning about something they cannot do.

Hence the requirement of a bit of a rep needed in the first place - to learn a bit before griping about things which while might be annoying, are valid, and do work in the interest of the greater good.

And is probably already covered if one searches for a bit more than a bloody nanosecond!

I don't know what message users with <5 rep get when trying to ask on Meta, however it should (if it doesn't) be quite informative, linking to the help centre clearly, and clearly state:

> As you are a new user, please use the help section, and importantly
>   search thoroughly on Meta as your question has likely already been
>   asked and answered.
>
> If you feel you still need to ask a question, please do not bypass the
>   min 5 rep requirement by posting on someone else's Meta question, or
>   by asking on a site you do have posting privileges.
>
> This will not get your question answered, and will likely just gain
>   downvotes, hindering your progress towards gaining the required rep
>   for asking your question.
>
> 5 rep is very easy to earn!.