# Meta's rep minimum seems to have undesirable consequences

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, meta

There is, I believe, a requirement for [a minimum 5 rep](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271202/whats-the-thought-behind-the-5-rep-limit-for-asking-questions-on-meta) to ask a question on meta.
I think twice this week I have seen ([one example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280779/i-want-to-ask-excelquestion-with-picture)) questions migrated to meta that were asked on SO by people with less than 5 rep.

The 5 rep minimum seems, sometimes, to mean that people are posting on SO questions that are being read by many, downvoted by some and that go through the VTC process before ending up on meta.

Can this be “fixed” so that less time is wasted all round?

Comment: pretty sure that this "harmful consequence" is better than the alternative, ie have spam bots posting to meta.  no?

Comment: Prior to the MSO/MSE split, there was no rep minimum. Half? the questions that got posted to MSO were programming questions - many of which were question-banned users trying to evade the ban.

Comment: @pnuts Well they have to start somewhere, no? If we put a 5 rep limit on SO AND MSO.... we simply won't have new guys.  But seriously, I think there are less reviewers on MSO so close votes would be worse, and would require more time from moderators instead of having normal users review it.  I didn't even think about Mysticial's point, which is valid as well

Answer (score 9):

In [the before time](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/), you could ask on meta having earned no reputation.

So new folks posted programming questions here out of confusion or in hope that they would get more attention. Which they did. Not the good kind of attention, but attention all the same. That's become much less common with the introduction of the reputation requirement.

Now, you can't post on meta until you've done *something* of note on the site itself. Asked a question or posted an answer that got one upvote, made 3 edits, whatever. Which, given this is the site for talking about the site, makes some sense: if you haven't really *used* the site, what do you have to talk about?

For those occasional questions from new users that are both more appropriate on meta *and* not a complete waste of time, migration is fairly easy and usually quickly accomplished.

Comment: The alternatives seem to involve even more wasted time, so... Yeah, lesser of two evils.

Comment: We already bar migration from Meta->main. Main->Meta is *encouraged* for posts that are a better fit here; it's actually easier than spam-deletion most of the time.

Comment: Wouldn't two edits be enough?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheElfHat Is correct. All users start with 1 reputation, approved edits give two reputation. 1 + 2(approved edit) = 5.