# Don't treat closed questions on meta as rejected migrations from main

Tags: feature-request, meta, migration

What I find striking is that for **none** of the rejected migrations, pushing a question from meta back to main helps things any.

While the appropriateness even for meta differs between them, it's arguably either the only appropriate place, or at least the place which comes closest.

Thus, my feature-request:
**Never reject any migration from main finding its way to meta**.

---

For your perusal, the ten most recent rejections:

1. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299592 A bit ranty, got an answer explaining why it's not in SE's bailwick, and some explanation for the perceived inferiority due to unfamiliarity.
2. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299554 Someone misunderstanding SO and why it works (there is lots of good content) but doesn't work for him asking (his questions are bad). He was set straight.
3. (10K) [Inspect thoroughly methodically and in detail, interpret this users reputation and comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299462) Someone repeatedly bringing up the same thing. It certainly belongs on meta, if anywhere.
4. (10K) [How to delete Stack Overflow Account](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299150) Deleted by community because account deleted. Who would have thought?
5. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299096 Wanting to dynamically modify the representation of code on SO. Unclear may be, but it belongs on meta!
6. (10K) [Stack Useful? Or moderator hell?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298766) Quite ranty. But if anywhere, it belongs on meta, where it got useful answers anyway.
7. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298487 About badges and scope. Back to main, you are kidding?
8. (10K) [Why is this site such assholes to beginners?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298257) Someone mistaking SE for a tutoring/forum site for teaching the basics and ranting. No need to move it back to main, though deleting it outright (as happened) is indubitably best.
9. (10K) [Is JavaScript the most popular language on StackOverflow right now?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297536) Not a gem, even though from a 22K+ user. A joke question, too meta for meta.
10. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297453 Question about html in posts. Wonder why it was closed as unclear, but that's not important here. Very much a meta question.

Comment: current way is just blindly copying the way how migrations work between main sites. This appears to be totally inconsistent with the ideas laid out in [What is a meta for?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240440/165773)

Comment: Maybe part of the problem is probably that most of the users that close vote these are also active on meta or at least have a similar idea about how the sites should work. We don't like unreasonable posts. Best is in all these cases to find a duplicate and close vote against that one because that prevents a migration back. If no duplicate exist those questions should remain open because they are not crap enough (they are migrated after all), un-rant-ified and wait for answers.

Comment: Counter proposal: don't migrate complete crap from main when it could just be closed there? Why close it twice, when we could do it once?

Comment: @TZHX: That would only works on the complete crap (nearly all of which is *not* migrated anyway). And only after you succeed in convincing everyone on main that if it's a meta-topic, it doesn't belong on meta if it's sub-par (that's arguable, and snowflakes chance in hell comes near).

Comment: @TZHX if it was that four 3K users would routinely vote to migrate blatantly inappropriate questions to meta, we'd have much _much_ bigger problems than discussed here. Think of it, it's own site meta, at 3k rep it's hard to get its topic wrong. Have you _ever_ seen coding question migrated here from main site?

Comment: @gnat I'm not really sure what the "problems" being discussed here are. What issues does it acting as it would elsewhere cause?

Comment: @TZHX my point is, all questions migrated here are genuine meta, it just doesn't happen that we get "complete crap from main" - at least not in the sense that it should be migrated back. Voted down, closed, deleted - same as sometimes happens to usual, non-migrated questions - yes, sure. Migrated back to main as blatant off-topic - no, it just doesn't happen.

Comment: @gnat did anyone suggest it did?

Comment: @TZHX looks like we both agree that it didn't happen that folks from main site migrate to meta questions that should be sent back, don't we? if so then it doesn't make sense to send them back, right?

Comment: But what harm does it cause that needs a special case? How many of the questions that are closed on main (to migrate here), then closed here and "rejected migrations" aren't already deleted on main by the time they're closed here? My point is why send it here when it could just be closed / deleted once? It's the same reasons I dont think "well let's just migrate everything opinion based to programmers and let them deal with it", general principle being that questions shouldn't be migrated if they don't meet the quality standards of the target site -- this should include migrations to meta.

Comment: to start with, it breaks edit-then-reopen functionality (rejected migrations are locked). More generally, as pointed in [first comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299599/dont-treat-closed-questions-on-meta-as-rejected-migrations-from-main#comment222196_299599), it goes against ideas that meta is to be operated differently from main site

Comment: @TZHX I think the problem is that it clutters up SO itself. It's better to have garbage meta questions on meta than it is to have garbage meta questions on the main site where users looking for code answers might stumble across it. The linked and related questions lists come to mind as places they might show up. Not to mention that if a user who's still learning stumbles across it, they're missing an opportunity to learn what does and doesn't belong on meta.

Comment: Am I the only one who understands what @TZHX is saying? Yes, meta posts should be posted on meta, not main. But even meta isn't tolerant of shitposts - if a post is going to get closed on meta anyway, then close and delete it *wherever it was posted*. Don't waste time sending it here. The "Inspect thoroughly" etc post is one example. Meta regulars know who that guy is, *yet routinely migrate every one of his shitposts to meta* as if anything else was going to happen besides me having to go and delete both the meta copy and the main copy before suspending the user. You think I get off on that?

Comment: The point of having rejected migrations to meta is not only to teach users to migrate to the correct sites, but also to teach them not to migrate crap, *even if that crap is on-topic for the target site*.

Comment: @BoltClock Thank you. I'm glad that I'm not *entirely* alone in my opinions. :)

Comment: @jpmc26: The reason that it clutters up SO itself is mostly because the user chose to post it there to begin with. Migrating a post from one site to another doesn't cause the original copy to disappear right away - it still has to be deleted by a moderator or the Roomba after the fact. Having garbage in two places is certainly not better than one.

Comment: I also don't think it's right to allow low rep users to circumvent the requirement for 5 rep to participate on Meta by posting a Meta question on the Main site. IIRC, that "Inspect thoroughly" person has done this before: post a question on main with a request that it be migrated to Meta because they don't have enough rep to post here directly. And it worked!

Comment: @BoltClock: Sure, if it teaches users to migrate/post to the right site, that's good. But that's not what it does most of the time, and many deletions/closures on meta should not have happened, are temporary, or at least do not actually indicate inappropriateness for meta. One of the problems is that a rejected post cannot be re-opened.

Comment: @BSMP: That user was well aware of meta and had well more than enough rep to post here - they simply chose not to.

Comment: @BoltClock: Now I have no idea who "this user" is... though I don't deny that's happening in some of those cases.

Comment: @BoltClock - It must have been another user then; I know I've seen a question that actually had "Please move this to Meta" in the question itself before.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271202/1157054

Comment: @BSMP Possibly that same user, but on one of the additional accounts they used to get around a suspension.