# Why is there a "migration rejected" notice and then a successful migration description?

Tags: bug, notifications

I saw [this drama-filled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333055/my-account-was-deleted-and-my-co-workers-account-was-suspended) post earlier and it has a notice that says:

> **migration rejected** from stackoverflow.com 3 hours ago
>
> This question came from our site for professional and enthusiast programmers. Votes, comments, and answers are locked due to the question being closed here, but it may be eligible for editing and reopening on the site where it originated.

But if you look at the [post's history here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/333055/revisions) it states very early:

> **Post Migrated Here** from stackoverflow.com   occurred 7 hours ago

This doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 36):

The question was originally asked on Stack Overflow, and then migrated here to Meta (correctly, since it is off-topic for Stack Overflow and belongs here).

Then, the question (after having been migrated to Meta) was closed as "off-topic" because it "does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community". Putting aside the appropriateness of that closure reason, **when migrated questions are closed, the migration is automatically rejected, sending the question back to the site on which it was originally asked**.

That's why the question is now [locked on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333055/my-account-was-deleted-and-my-co-workers-account-was-suspended), and [appears on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39114088/my-account-was-deleted-and-my-co-workers-account-was-suspended) just as if it were asked there and closed normally. The sordid story of its migratory trek is only visible in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39114088/revisions).

Now, you might ask, why does closure reject a migration? Normally, this makes a great deal of sense. If a crap question gets migrated, say, from Stack Overflow to Super User, and the Super User folks close it, the migration gets rejected. The question gets sent back to its originating site with the implicit message "we do not want your garbage".

*However*, rejecting migrations to Meta sites does not actually make sense. I've been meaning to write up a bug report for this for nearly a year now, but just haven't taken the time. Meta sites are supposed to be "black holes", where things can be migrated *in* but can never be migrated *out*. These migration rejections are a back door that allows questions to escape the black hole of Meta. That is just as dangerous as it sounds.

Comment: related feature request: [Don't treat closed questions on meta as rejected migrations from main](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299599/839601) "if it was that four 3K users would routinely vote to migrate blatantly inappropriate questions to meta, we'd have much _much_ bigger problems than discussed here. Think of it, it's own site meta, at 3k rep it's hard to get its topic wrong. Have you _ever_ seen coding question migrated here from main site?"

Comment: That is why I always try to find a duplicate to close such migration cases because those aren't rejected once closed as dupe. I sometimes redefine what *exact* means, ending up with a *this will do* target. Migrations are always tagged discussion, and we have some gold dupe hammers around in that tag ...

Comment: You're right, these locked migration cases are a particular problem on Meta. They often require manual intervention by a moderator to clean them up, because no one else can touch the locked posts. Erroneous migrations of technical questions to Meta are vanishingly rare, so the reasons for locking them don't really apply.